# Python: How can I make my tkinter app exit properly?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, exit

I need to know how to do this on a mac because whenever I try quitting it, I have to force quit it. Is there a proper way when the user clicks the exit button that Tkinter will exit normally?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how. I just put a simple `exit()` command after the main loop.